# Добавление телефонного номера в контакты

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Всем доброго времени суток!

Столкнулся с вопросом, существует ли возможность добавить в контактную книгу номер телефона с сайта?

То есть при клике на ссылку что бы открывалась тел.книга с предзаполнеными полями/полем?

Ни в гугле, ни в спецификации html5 я не нашел ответа на этот вопрос. Может кто сталкивался?

Или допустим у нас есть несколько полей и кнопка, при клике на которую у нас открывается тел.книга с так же предзаполнеными полями, которые у нас на сайте.

Comment: не возможно....\

Comment: Может вот это http://gnatkovsky.com.ua/kak-sdelat-ssylki-na-viber-whatsapp-telegram.html

Answer (score 0):

Только если надо набрать номер, работает на ка iphone так и на android, на windows phone не проверял...

```html
<a href="tel:+78125346202">+78125346202</a>
```